# Blood in urine without seeing it...?

Tags: blood, urine, kidney

I came from my doctor and he did a urine sample and said there was blood in my urine. I've never seen "blood" in my urine or had any issues with my kidneys  so I was perplexed by this. Is this possible to have blood in urine without actually seeing it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. what you are describing sounds like microscopic hematuria (1). Sometimes red blood cells(RBC) are not numerous enough to be visible in  urine. Yet, when tested, RBCs are detected.

(1) http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMcp012694

Comment: This is so close to being a really good answer. A reference with a little more explanation would be a big improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of blood in the urine is called [Hematuria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematuria). It can be detected in the microscopic lab tests. Please contact a nephrologist doctor for quick treatment.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible and it is called microscopic hematuria. Etiologies of microscopic hematuria range from incidental causes to more serious ones.[Further assessment is needed to stablish its meaning.](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2006/0515/p1748.html)

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: This is the same answer as was already posted, and of less use as there is nothing corroborating it.